# Vertices not behaving smoothly after Subdivide

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

This model was made by extruding 2 Bezier curves. I tried joining them at the four vertices but the subsurface doesn't work.

This is the result. I've tried to delete and recreate the vertices several ways but I always get the same or similar result.
[image]
[image]

Comment: This looks like the normals are flipped on half of the model, so subdivision surface claims the outermost edge as the interpolated midpoint between these faces.

Answer (score 1):

Face orientation (normals) was the problem. Once I rebuilt the parts from scratch and made sure to extrude both wireframe in the same direction the issue went away.